# #1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_column_info' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin, xampp

I've recently just installed XAMPP and I'm pretty new to all of this. I was trying to open a new DB in phpmyadmin, but it wrote me this error - `#1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_column_info' doesn't exist`.

I looked it up on the web and it said that I need to run a query of `create_tables.sql`on the DB "phpmyadmin", but everytime I click on that database it just errors me the same error as before - `#1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_column_info' doesn't exist`.

Can anyone help me with it?

Thanks, Dan

Answer (score 7):

None of the answers above or on other posts worked.

I solved the issue by going into my file explorer and deleting the phpmyadmin directory. Then you can run create_tables.sql in phpmyadmin and it should all work from there.

phpmyadmin directory can be found in C:\xampp\mysql\data

create_tables.sql is in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\sql

Don't forget to restart xampp.

Answer (score 3):

You will find `create_tables.sql.gz` file in /usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/examples/` dir

[image: phpmyadmin examples]

Extract it, `sudo file-roller create_tables.sql.gz` and change `pma_` prefix by `pma__` or vice versa

[image: create_tables.sql.gz]

Then import you new script SQL from phpmyadmin in your browser

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an optional feature that require to create tables from create_tables.sql

You can disable it just edit the file config.inc.php and comment these lines:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows
If you're using xampp since php 5.6.19 or later on initial setup you need to drop the phpmyadmin database and recreate it using the scripts in 
X:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\sql